# How can I Extract only the text from cells which are formatted in a specific way. (excel)

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I wonder if I can get some help. I am importing a html file which places text into the first column of a spreadsheet. The text will appear formated in various ways for example it may be of a colour or in italics, bold or a combination.

Is there a way to extract the various text from the column based upon it's format and copy the text into another column by VBA? Please see my example below of what I would like to achieve.

Many thanks in advance.

Screenshot shows what I would like to achieve

[image: screenshot]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: *Is there a way to extract the various text from the column based upon it's format and copy the text into another column by VBA?*  Yes. Using conditional logic based on relevant properties of the cell object.

Comment: Simply loop every character and check its properties. That's all you need to do.

Comment: Here is an example for Bold  http://superuser.com/questions/1081267/excel-2013-vba-script-needed-for/1081291#1081291

Answer (score 0):

you may start with this code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim word As Variant, colOff As Variant
    Dim colOffStrng As String

    With Worksheets("MySheet") '<~~ change "MySheet" with whatever name your sheet has
        For Each cell In .Range("A4:A" & .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<~~consider cells in column A from row 4 to the last non empty cell containing text values only
            For Each word In Split(WorksheetFunction.Trim(cell)) '<~~ check each word in the cell. a space is assumed as words separator, multiple spaces considered as one space
                colOffStrng = "" '<~~ initialize the offsets string
                With cell.Characters(InStr(cell, word), Len(word)).Font '<~~ consider the Font property of the word first character
                    If .Bold Then colOffStrng = colOffStrng & "1 " '<~~ Bold is 1 column offset from column A
                    If .Italic Then colOffStrng = colOffStrng & "2 " '<~~ Italic is 2 columns offset from column A
                    Select Case .ColorIndex '<~~ consider the ColorIndex property of the word first character
                      Case 3 'red
                          colOffStrng = colOffStrng & "3 " '<~~ red is 3 columns offset from column A
                      Case 5 'blue
                          colOffStrng = colOffStrng & "4 " '<~~ blue is 4 columns offset from column A
                    End Select
                End With
                For Each colOff In Split(Trim(colOffStrng)) '<~~ loop through each column offset stored
                    cell.Offset(, colOff) = word '<~~ fill proper cell with the word
                Next colOff
            Next word
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

where I assumed the following:

- all characters of each word share the same formatting
- formatting style columns are:

  - column B for Bold words
  - column C for Italic words
  - column D for Red words (ColorIndex = 3)
  - column E for Blue words (ColorIndex = 5)
  - for their combination you may use formulas directly typed in cells, like

    `=IF(C4=D4,C4,"")` in cell H4, where to put combination of "Italic" and "Red" formatting

of course the "combination" can be furtherly automatized, perhaps with Boolean algebra

Comment: @MikeeS: did you get through it?